# retrieving image from image url

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsthread

how to get `uiimage` from a `nsurl` other than using the method `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`
There is another problem the ui elements are not working while a `nsthread` is running

Comment: I would also like to know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I tend to use NSOperationQueue.

See

http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/managingconcurrency.html

http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=549

Answer (score 1):

The AFNetworking library from Gowalla has a nice and easy way to load images in the background. See [here](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It will be something like this.

```
ASIHTTPRequest * request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSData * responseData = [request responseData];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load image : %@", [request.error localizedDescription]);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: I guess the question is to retrieve image without using NSData.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid NSData? (what's wrong with NSData...?)

I thought the question was how to load UIImage without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

For background image download, you could try

```
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link:http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Download

AsyncImageView.h
AsyncImageView.m

add these files to your project and import it in your class

write down these lines wher yu want to add imagesubview:

AsyncImageView *asyncImageView=[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (80, 10, 70,20);];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
            [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:url];
            asyncImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            [myimageView addSubview:asyncImageView];
            [asyncImageView release];

you will get